# Firestore not reading from new Collections

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i am having a weird issue where my queries don't return anything from new collections i just created.

i'm doing simple query which is to return the number of docs in the collections

```
getNumberOfFollowers () {
  CollectionRef2.path(path: 'followers').doc(currentUser).collection('userFollowers').snapshots().listen((value) {
   numberOfFollowers.value = value.docs.length;
   log(value.docs.length.toString(),name: 'numberOfFollowers');

  });
}
```

i ran the exact same query from the console and it's working, so it's not a rules issue,

i also ran same request but from old collections and also worked !

[image: query from console]

and before you ask , YES the function is being called in OnInit(), and the log comes back with value of 0;

this is my firestore rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;  
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you use the wrapper of `cloud_firestore` but with the basic package you can do something like this:

```
Stream<int> getCount(String currentUser) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('followers')
        .doc(currentUser)
        .collection('userFollowers')
        .snapshots()
        .map((event) => event.docs.length);
  }
```